# R: Iterating over a series of dates to create multiple intervals

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, lubridate

Good evening. I'm looking for a simpler solution to an obscure task I have with a dataset. I've already solved it using dplyr, but I was wondering if someone in the community had a more elegant solution, possibly using purrr for my own edification.

I have a toy dataset here with 3 study IDs and 3 dose dates for a medication. One dose is NA. I'd like to generate 2 new variables: one named "int_1" to represent the interval in time between the first two doses, and then "int_2" to represent the interval between the second and third dose.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
study_id <- c(1001, 1002, 1003)
dose_1 <- c('1/1/10', '2/3/12', '1/1/13')
dose_2 <- c('1/10/10', '2/4/12', '1/2/13')
dose_3 <- c(NA, '3/1/12', '2/2/13')
df <- tibble(study_id, dose_1, dose_2, dose_3)
df <- df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(contains('dose')),
            funs(mdy))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  study_id dose_1     dose_2     dose_3    
     <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>    
1     1001 2010-01-01 2010-01-10 NA        
2     1002 2012-02-03 2012-02-04 2012-03-01
3     1003 2013-01-01 2013-01-02 2013-02-02
```

What would be your simplest solution to obtain the following (only the first interval shown). Here I have used the dplyr/lubridate method that I'm familiar with. In reality, I have 42 different doses, so I'm looking for something easier than copying and pasting the following code 41 times to make the different intervals. I need something that can deal with the missing doses, as well.

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(int_1 = interval(dose_1, dose_2),
         int_1 = int_1/months(1))

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  study_id dose_1     dose_2     dose_3      int_1
     <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>      <dbl>
1     1001 2010-01-01 2010-01-10 NA         0.290 
2     1002 2012-02-03 2012-02-04 2012-03-01 0.0345
3     1003 2013-01-01 2013-01-02 2013-02-02 0.0323
```

Any alternatives to this brute force approach much appreciated. Something in purrr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, it is better to have data in long format and then perform the calculation

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -study_id, names_to = 'dose') %>%
  group_by(study_id) %>%
  mutate(temp = interval(value, lead(value))/months(1)) %>%
  mutate(int = paste0('int', row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(dose, int), values_from = c(value, temp)) %>%
  select(-ncol(.))

#  study_id value_dose_1_int1 value_dose_2_int2 value_dose_3_int3 temp_dose_1_int1 temp_dose_2_int2
#     <dbl> <date>            <date>            <date>                       <dbl>            <dbl>
#1     1001 2010-01-01        2010-01-10        NA                          0.290            NA    
#2     1002 2012-02-03        2012-02-04        2012-03-01                  0.0345            0.897
#3     1003 2013-01-01        2013-01-02        2013-02-02                  0.0323            1
```

Comment: Nice, I like this approach. I was unfamiliar with the lead() function. Very helpful. Thanks!